# How long have the Inhumans inhabited the moon in TV show?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, inhumans-2017

Looking at http://marvel.com/universe/Attilan the Earth-616 Inhumans have been inhabiting the moon for a relatively short period of time: seven thousand years ago they began to live in isolation on an island in Atlantic ocean. Then in mid-20th century they moved to Himalayas. Some time after that(possibly in the 1980s) they moved again, this time to the Moon.

However, in the new TV series, which are probably in MCU I get the feeling that they have been on the moon for generations at least. Is there any more precise information on how much time has passed since their exodus? A century? Millennia?

Comment: Related to the question about why they speak English.

Comment: @Adamant picking up Earth's transmissions?

Answer (score 2):

Using the sources of *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, *Inhumans*, and the Marvel Cinematic Universe wiki, here is what can be determined:

- Thousands of years ago, the first Inhuman, Alveus, was created by the Kree
- Alveus, after leading a rebellion against the Kree, was banished from Earth by his fellow Inhumans
- Over the centuries, a society created by Alveus' followers evolved, eventually becoming HYDRA
- Somewhere in that timespan, a group of Inhumans left Earth for the moon
- The Inhuman Royal Family has been on the Moon for at least three generations
- Technology that doesn't exist on Earth has managed to develop, but the Royal Family is unaware of some of Earth's newer technology

My estimate is that the Inhumans have been on the Moon for at least one hundred years. If new information comes up, feel free to edit this answer.